# Experimenting with algorithms: Is there an inverse to this algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, encryption, c++17

**EDIT** - *-I renamed the title of this and changed the wording of the question as some have pointed out that this appears to be more of a hashing algorithm than an encryption - decryption algorithm. However, I will leaven the name of the functions as they are. I will also append my full code at the end along with a link to where you can find the dictionary file I'm using as some weren't sure where or how I was generating the numbers to be used in the algorithm(s).-*

---

I'm working on a custom algorithm and so far and the results seem to be good for the first part. However the calculation that I'm using for the inverse I'm not sure if there is one or not.

The pseudo code is as follows:

```
for each character in string:
    new character in return string = (a|b) & c + 'a';
    where:
        a is a large value based on the occurrence of that character 
          based on an alpha text dictionary file
        b is a small value based on the occurrence of that character 
          found in the analyzed string to be encrypted.
        c is the current string converted to lowercase.
```

My encryption function:

```
std::string encrypt(const std::string& sentence, std::map<char, std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>>& dist) {
    std::string encrypted = "";

    // take each character from our original sentence
    // find it in the map and perform the calculation.
    // if the character is non alphabetical just add it. 
    for (auto& s : sentence)        
        if (std::isalpha(s)) {
            char c = std::tolower(s);
            char a = dist[std::remove_const_t<char>(c)].first;  // large value
            char b = dist[std::remove_const_t<char>(c)].second; // small value
            char res = (a | b) % c + 'a';
            encrypted.push_back(res);
        }
        else
            encrypted.push_back(s);

    return encrypted;
}
```

Decryption function:

```
std::string decrypt(const std::string& encrypted, std::map<char, std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>>& dist) {
    std::string decrpyted = "";

    for (auto& s : encrypted) {    
        // ? Is there an inverse to the above?
        // Also how would I handle the non alpha characters that
        // were unchanged?  
    }    
    return decrpyted;
}
```

I changed the result of the function to this:

```
char res = (a % b) % c + 'a';
```

The text appears to be scrambled. Is there a way to reverse this?

---

**EDIT** - *-Full source code and link to dictionary file-*

[Github:Dictionary File](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words)

**Full Source**

```
#include <cctype>
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>

void generateCryptoBaseMapFromFile(std::string filename, std::map<char, unsigned>& weights);
void printWeights(std::string filename, std::map<char, unsigned> weights);
void analyzeTextAndGenerateDistributionMap(std::string contents, std::map<char,unsigned>& weights, std::map<char, std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>>& dist);       
void printDistributionMap(std::string filename, std::map<char, std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>>& dist);
std::string encrypt(const std::string& sentence, std::map<char, std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>>& dist);
std::string decrypt(const std::string& encrypted, std::map<char, std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>>& dist);

int main() {        
    std::string filenameIn( "words_alpha.txt" );
    std::map<char, unsigned> weights;
    generateCryptoBaseMapFromFile(filenameIn, weights);    

    std::string filenameOut("character_distribution.txt");
    printWeights(filenameOut, weights);
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::string sentence("I enjoyed myself when I went to the shore. I had a blast swimming in the cool ocean on a hot summer day with a mild breeze.");
    std::map<char, std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>> distMap;
    analyzeTextAndGenerateDistributionMap(sentence, weights, distMap);
    printDistributionMap(filenameOut, distMap);
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::string encrypted = encrypt(sentence, distMap);
    std::cout << encrypted << '\n';

    // std::string decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, dist);
    // std::cout << decrypted << '\n'; // should match original sentence.

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void generateCryptoBaseMapFromFile(std::string filename, std::map<char, unsigned>& weights) {
    unsigned int count[1U << CHAR_BIT]{};
    std::ifstream in;

    in.open(filename);
    if (!in.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Could not open " << filename << " for reading.";
        return;
    }

    for (std::istream_iterator<char> it(in), it_eof; it != it_eof; ++it)
        ++count[std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(*it))];

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < (1U << CHAR_BIT); ++i)
        if (std::isalpha(i) && count[i])
            weights[static_cast<char>(i)] = count[i];

    in.close();
}

void printWeights(std::string filename, std::map<char, unsigned> weights) {
    std::ostringstream ostream;
    for (auto& u : weights)
        ostream << u.first << ' ' << u.second << '\n';

    // print to file & cout
    std::ofstream out;

    out.open(filename, std::ios::trunc);
    out << ostream.str();
    std::cout << ostream.str();
}

void analyzeTextAndGenerateDistributionMap(std::string contents, std::map<char,unsigned>& weights, std::map<char, std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>>& dist) {
    std::cout << "\nAnalyzing the following sentence:\n" << contents << '\n';

    unsigned int count[1U << CHAR_BIT]{};
    std::istringstream istream( contents );

    for (std::istream_iterator<char> it(istream), it_eof; it != it_eof; ++it) 
        ++count[std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(*it))];

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < (1U << CHAR_BIT); ++i) {
        if (std::isalpha(i) && count[i]) {
            unsigned weight = weights.at(static_cast<unsigned char>(i));
            dist[static_cast<unsigned char>(i)] = std::make_pair(weight, count[i]);
        }
    }
}

void printDistributionMap(std::string filename, std::map<char, std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>>& dist) {
    std::ofstream out;
    out.open(filename, std::ios::app);
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << "\n\n";
    out << os.str();
    std::cout << os.str();
    os.str(std::string());
    os.clear();

    for (auto& m : dist) {
        os << m.first << " (" << m.second.first << "," << m.second.second << ")\n";
    }
    out << os.str();
    std::cout << os.str();
}

std::string encrypt(const std::string& sentence, std::map<char, std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>>& dist) {
    std::string encrypted = "";

    // take each character from original string find it in the map 
    // and perform the calculations. If the character is non 
    // alpahbetical we just add it to the string. 
    for (auto& s : sentence)        
        if (std::isalpha(s)) {
            char c = std::tolower(s);
            char a = dist[c].first;
            char b = dist[c].second;
            // the following formula must have an inverse!
            unsigned char res = (a % (b * c)) /*+ 'a'*/;
            std::cout << +res << ' ';
            encrypted.push_back(res);
        }
        else
            encrypted.push_back(s);

    std::cout << "\n\n";
    return encrypted;
}

std::string decrypt(const std::string& encrypted, std::map<char, std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>>& dist) {
    std::string decrpyted = "";

    for (auto& s : encrypted) {
        // ???    
    }

    return decrpyted;
}
```

Comment: If you need to see my other code to find out what kind of numbers I'm generating let me know and I'll update my question, but for all tense and purposes I don't think the number's would be relevant here, just the formula should suffice.

Comment: By performing a bitwise *and*ing, you "lose" data, since `0110101&x`, means that the bits where the left operand is `0`, are set to `0`, but there is no way to "recover" the original value.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with C++. But as far as C++ goes, `std::remove_const_t<char>` is `char`, and `c` is already a `char`... so you can just write `dist[c].first` and `dist[c].second`.

Comment: @Barry I was trying that without removing the const, but Visual Studio was complaining when I tried to access the map from the character coming from the string.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you; I was thinking it that, but wanted to verify. I might have to redesign my function to make sure that there is a valid inverse!

Comment: Bitwise ORing loses information as well...

Comment: @Barry that's odd; I removed the `remove_const` and Visual Studio is not complaining now...

Comment: Why not use a well-known, well-tested, and virtually unbreakable algorithm, like e.g. AES (Rijndael)?

Comment: You're not intending to design something for practical use are you?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I know I could; I'm just doing this for self practice and experimentation! I'm taking the approach of using an alpha text based dictionary file. I read in all the characters and create a histogram of the occurrence of all the characters in that dictionary file. Then I take that same algorithm and apply that to the text I want to encrypt, So the large number will be constant based on the dictionary file used, the small number will vary depending on the text being encrypted - decrypted.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I'm experimenting with ideas, but wanted clarification if my calculation has an inverse or not; that's all.

Comment: `char c = std::tolower(s);` immediately eliminates the possibility of decrypting to get back the original character with the original case.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark You are correct, I'm not using this for practical use, I'm experimenting with ideas and concepts, self practice of writing algorithms.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I'm thinking about expanding my other functions not shown here to include all printable characters and to ignore white space.

Comment: You don't seem to have an encryption key anywhere, which means that you have an obfuscation/hashing algorithm, not an [encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) algorithm. I doubt that your algorithm is reversible, and even if it is the process definitely won't be simple.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang Good point; this could be considered more of a hashing algorithm than an encryption - decryption at first glance, but the idea was the fact that the encryption key would be the map of values generated from the specific dictionary file that I'm using. I'm self taught with no formal education; so I learn by doing, trial and error!

Comment: I appended another technique to see if there is an inverse or not. Then again; it would have an inverse if a & b are relatively prime...

Comment: While invertible functions can be built out of non-invertible parts, a simple way to guarantee invertibility is composing invertible functions.

Comment: @Harold true enough... just been at this a while, and my mind is starting to get tired, lol, might need a to take a break for a bit...

Comment: I mean, it might make a good hashing algorithm, but yeah, I agree it's more of a hash, not an encryption.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to determine whether the performed operations are revertible without seeing how `dist` is generated. However there's a fairly simple method to find out. What your algorithm does is essentially mapping any alphabetic character to a specific fixed value, which can be trivially precomputed:

```
for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
    std::cout << c << ': ' << (int) ((dist[c].first | dist[c].second) % c + 'a') << '\n';
```

A guess based on what I can tell from the code is that it is not invertible simply because the mapping won't be bijective in most cases. Due to the size of `c`, unless there happens something magical in the calculation of `dist`, at least some alphabetic characters will be mapped to codes that are taken by non-alphabetical characters, thus producing a collision.

If you want to restrict the encryption to alphabetic characters, you should make sure that only those are valid output-codes. Last but not least most logical operators as well as the modulo operator trim your data down, which is most likely not helpful in making the whole thing reversible.

And an important note (you've probably already heard it, but still):
Never use a self-developed algorithm for anything practical, unless you're Bruce Schneier.

Comment: @FrancisCugler that was just a small note for anyone else visiting this question. It's pretty much a piece of boilerplate for any answer to a question about rolling your own encryption-algorithm. Anyways, encryption is an interesting topic, enjoy ;)

Comment: Yeah it's not for practical uses, it's just for self practice, creating and testing algorithms, etc. If I was writing a practical application I would use algorithms that already exist that have been well tested. I'm not trying to "reinvent the wheel" here. Just practicing to strengthen my abilities, not just in coding, but also in the underlying mathematics that are involved. This was just for fun!